# Почему не работает this.Method в switch?

Tags: java, консоль, switch

```
void Menue{
void Menu()throws java.io.IOException{
             char menu;
             String name;            
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\tMENU");
            System.out.println("1. Bioraphy");
            System.out.println("2.Start game");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Choose one: ");
 menu= (char) System.in.read();
swihch(menue){
case '1' : System.out.println (".......");
this.Menue;
break;
case '2' : ..........
}
```

я хочу, чтобы метод Menue выполнялся еще раз после выбора 1. Он вызывается, но ввести char menu я не имею возможности. Выводится только System.out.prinln (); и потом break;

```
case '1' : System.out.println (".......");
this.Menue;
break;
```

Comment: метод this.Menu();

Comment: Автор, прочитай книжку про Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите следующий код, адаптируйте под ваши нужды.

```
class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
      showMenu();
      char n = '0';      
      while(n!='3') {
         n = (char)System.in.read();

         switch(n) {
            case '1' : System.out.println("Select 1");
                       showMenu();
                       break;
            case '2' : System.out.println("Select 2");
                       showMenu();
                       break;
         }
      }
   }
   public static void showMenu() {
      System.out.println("1. Number one.");
      System.out.println("2. Number two.");
      System.out.println("3. Exit.");
   }
}
```

Что касается вашего кода, то он не скомпилируется, так что о выполнении или не выполнении какого-то метода в вашем коде говорить рано.